# How to print the exception in selenium and testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have an issue that I am facing in java and selenium and testng.
I am trying to locate an element, and in the test I made a mistake and the element not exists  (xpath not returned answer).
The problem is that the exception i  printed is not the full selenium exception,(I want to be printed that the element not exists or something regarding selenium)
** the problem is in the clickelementwhenclickable method, that not find the element, however not print the full exception
Here is my Code:
this is the most basic method that click on element ():

```
public void ClickElementWhenClickable(By locator) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_WAITE, SECONDS);
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        while (Instant.now().isBefore(now.plusSeconds(IMPLICIT_WAITE))) {
            try {
                new WebDriverWait(driver, IMPLICIT_WAITE).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();

                return;
            } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                // do nothing, loop again
            }

        }

        throw new Exception("Not able to click element <" + locator + "> within " + IMPLICIT_WAITE + "s.");
    }
```

this is the method that I use in the page that do something:

```
 public void selectCountry(String country,String index) throws Exception {
        By locator;
        openCountryList(index);
        String xpath;
        xpath = String.format(SELECT_FROM_DROPDOWN, country);
        locator = By.xpath(xpath);
        log.info("\n*******************************************\n try to select  : " + country + " from country list " + locator.toString() +
                "\n*******************************************\n"
        );
        ClickElementWhenClickable(locator);

    }
```

this is the test that run the method:

```
@Test(groups = {"supply", "ui"}, enabled = true, priority = 20) //20.
    public void enterDeviceTypeForVideoChild1() throws Exception {
        try {
            placementPage().scrollDown();
            placementPage().SelectDeviceType(placementDataObject.getGeoBidFloors().get(4).getDeviceType().deviceTypeValue(),"5");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.fail("Error enter device type:\n " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

and this is the exception when the test failed, that is without unable to locate element:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error enter device type:
 java.lang.Exception: Not able to click element <By.xpath: //li[contains(text(),'ctv')]> within 35s.

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
    at tests.ExPubPlacementPageTest.enterDeviceTypeForVideoChild1(ExPubPlacementPageTest.java:278)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

The problem that that the actual exception is not printed, unable to locate element. so this print is useless,How can I print the exception of selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for testNG listener( ITestListener ). you will have to implement the ITestListener and in that you will have to override the method called as onTestFailure. Please check the below code out.

```
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestNGListener implements ITestListener {

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {



        System.out.println(result.getThrowable().getMessage());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printStackTrace()` method of the `java.lang.Throwable` class, which is used to print this `Throwable` along with other details like class name and line number where the exception occurred.

```java
try {
    testException1(); 
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // print stack trace 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```